# CRC32 calculation in Python without using libraries

Tags: python, checksum, crc32, micropython

I  have been trying to get my head around CRC32 calculations without much success, the values that I seem to get do not match what I should get.

I am aware that Python has libraries that are capable of generating these checksums (namely zlib and binascii) but I do not have the luxury of being able to use them as the CRC functionality do not exist on the micropython.

So far I have the following code:

```
import binascii
import zlib
from array import array

poly = 0xEDB88320

table = array('L')
for byte in range(256):
    crc = 0
    for bit in range(8):
        if (byte ^ crc) & 1:
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
        else:
            crc >>= 1
        byte >>= 1
    table.append(crc)

def crc32(string):
    value = 0xffffffffL

    for ch in string:
        value = table[(ord(ch) ^ value) & 0x000000ffL] ^ (value >> 8)

    return value

teststring = "test"

print "binascii calc:  0x%08x" % (binascii.crc32(teststring) & 0xffffffff)
print "zlib calc:      0x%08x" % (zlib.crc32(teststring) & 0xffffffff)
print "my calc:        0x%08x" % (crc32(teststring))
```

Then I get the following output:

```
binascii calc:  0xd87f7e0c
zlib calc:      0xd87f7e0c
my calc:        0x2780810c
```

The binascii and zlib calculations agree where as my one doesn't.  I believe the calculated table of bytes is correct as I have compared it to examples available on the net.  So the issue must be the routine where each byte is calculated, could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't looked closely at your code, so I can't pinpoint the exact source of the error, but you can easily tweak it to get the desired output:

```
import binascii
from array import array

poly = 0xEDB88320

table = array('L')
for byte in range(256):
    crc = 0
    for bit in range(8):
        if (byte ^ crc) & 1:
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
        else:
            crc >>= 1
        byte >>= 1
    table.append(crc)

def crc32(string):
    value = 0xffffffffL
    for ch in string:
        value = table[(ord(ch) ^ value) & 0xff] ^ (value >> 8)

    return -1 - value

# test

data = (
    '',
    'test',
    'hello world',
    '1234',
    'A long string to test CRC32 functions',
)

for s in data:
    print repr(s)
    a = binascii.crc32(s)
    print '%08x' % (a & 0xffffffffL)
    b = crc32(s)
    print '%08x' % (b & 0xffffffffL)
    print
```

**output**

```
''
00000000
00000000

'test'
d87f7e0c
d87f7e0c

'hello world'
0d4a1185
0d4a1185

'1234'
9be3e0a3
9be3e0a3

'A long string to test CRC32 functions'
d2d10e28
d2d10e28
```

---

Here are a couple more tests that verify that the tweaked `crc32` gives the same result as `binascii.crc32`.

```
from random import seed, randrange

print 'Single byte tests...',
for i in range(256):
        s = chr(i)
        a = binascii.crc32(s) & 0xffffffffL
        b = crc32(s) & 0xffffffffL
        assert a == b, (repr(s), a, b)

print('ok')

seed(42)

print 'Multi-byte tests...'
for width in range(2, 20):
    print 'Width', width
    r = range(width)
    for n in range(1000):
        s = ''.join([chr(randrange(256)) for i in r])
        a = binascii.crc32(s) & 0xffffffffL
        b = crc32(s) & 0xffffffffL
        assert a == b, (repr(s), a, b)
print('ok')
```

**output**

```
Single byte tests... ok
Multi-byte tests...
Width 2
Width 3
Width 4
Width 5
Width 6
Width 7
Width 8
Width 9
Width 10
Width 11
Width 12
Width 13
Width 14
Width 15
Width 16
Width 17
Width 18
Width 19
ok
```

---

As discussed in the comments, the source of the error in the original code is that this CRC-32 algorithm inverts the initial crc buffer, and then inverts the final buffer contents. So `value` is initialised to `0xffffffff` instead of zero, and we need to return `value ^ 0xffffffff`, which can also be written as `~value & 0xffffffff`, i.e. invert `value` and then select the low-order 32 bits of the result.

Comment: You sir are a Godsend, thank you very much for your fast reply and solution!

Comment: @Cooper No worries. I'm not 100% confident of my tweak (due to mixing arithmetic with bitwise operations). It _appears_ to do the job correctly, but I'm a little concerned that it _might_ give the wrong answer in some corner case. OTOH, I just checked that it returns `ffffffff` when passed `'\xff\xff\xff\xff'`, so that's a good sign. :)

Comment: @Cooper After those additional tests, my confidence has increased. :) I'd be _very_ surprised if it returns the wrong result for any input.

Comment: it appears that 'return (value ^ 0xffffffff)' will remove the need to do an and operation on the result afterwards.  Bitwise arithmetic wasn't my strong point and it has been a while since.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Cooper Ah, of course! :) Another option is `return ~value & 0xffffffff`. Both of those are cleaner than `return (-1 - value) & 0xffffffff`. Your version is probably the best, since it uses the least number of operations.

Comment: FWIW, I have more examples of CRC code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360240/4014959

Answer (score 0):

If using binary data where the crc is chained over multiple buffers I used the following (using the OPs table):

```
def crc32(data, crc=0xffffffff):  
    for b in data:  
        crc = table[(b ^ crc) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8)  
    return crc
```

One can XOR the final result with -1 to agree with the online calculators.

```
crc = crc32(b'test')  
print('0x{:08x}'.format(crc))
  
crc = crc32(b'te')  
crc = crc32(b'st', crc)  
print('0x{:08x}'.format(crc))

print('xor: 0x{:08x}'.format(crc ^ 0xffffffff))
```

**output**

```
0x278081f3
0x278081f3
xor: 0xd87f7e0c
```