# 8-bit CRC calcuation in micropython

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, crc, micropython, crc8

I'm trying to implement and use an 8-bit CRC in micropython, to be used together with an ADC (ADS1235 Texas Instruments).

I've tried for some time now to rewrite existing programs (mainly implemented in C) and code this function from the bottom up but to no avail.

The functions bellow are the closest I could find to what I'm seeking. The CRC I'm using has the polynomial 0x07.

Functions taken from PM 2Ring comment "[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358646/how-to-calculate-this-crc-using-python)

```
def crc_16_CCITT(msg):
    poly = 0x8408
    crc = 0xffff
    for byte in msg:
        for _ in range(8):
            if (byte ^ crc) & 1:
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
            else:
                crc >>= 1
            byte >>= 1
    return crc ^ 0xffff
```

I've tried to use PM 2Ring table based implementation but that doesn't work either

```
def make_crc_table():
    poly = 0x8408
    table = []
    for byte in range(256):
        crc = 0
        for bit in range(8):
            if (byte ^ crc) & 1:
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
            else:
                crc >>= 1
            byte >>= 1
        table.append(crc)
    return table

table = make_crc_table()

def crc_16_fast(msg):
    crc = 0xffff
    for byte in msg:
        crc = table[(byte ^ crc) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8)
    return crc ^ 0xffff
```

My modifications to the first function can be seen bellow:

```
def crc_8_CCITT(msg):
    poly = 0x07
    crc = 0x00
    for byte in msg:
        for _ in range(8):
            if (byte ^ crc) & 1:
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
            else:
                crc >>= 1
            byte >>= 1
    return crc ^ 0x55
```

Comment: Do you have access to functioning C (or other) source that calculates the correct checksums?

Comment: Yes I've been using 3 online calculators to verify the result https://crccalc.com/, http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html?msclkid=391ec3dfcf8a11ecb97e68672e0a50b8 and https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/crc

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there some other hardware or software generating a particular CRC that you need to check? Or do you need to make a CRC that will be checked by something else you don't have control of? Or are you just trying to make an 8-bit CRC to use with code that you have control of on both ends? What are you looking at when you say it "doesn't work"? Note: online CRC calculators may or may not have anything to do with a particular CRC implementation you are trying to match.

Comment: Hey Mark, I've added a response to your answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

For the CRC it *appears* that you are trying to implement, which is a reflected CRC, you need to reflect the polynomial. You need `poly = 0xe0`.

The code can be simplified some. The for loop over the message can be:

```
for byte in msg:
    crc ^= byte
    for _ in range(8):
        if crc & 1:
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
        else:
            crc >>= 1
```

As to whether that is the CRC you actually need, I have no idea. Is the CRC you need reflected? Is the initial value zero? Where did the `0x55` come from? Do you have a specification of the CRC that you are not revealing to us? Do you have any example data for which you know the correct CRC value?

*Update:*

Based on the comment below, the OP needs to implement [CRC-8/I-432-1](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat.crc-8-i-432-1). It is *not* a reflected CRC, so the shifts are up, not down, has polynomial `0x07`, an initial value of zero, and a final exclusive or of `0x55`. The implementation for that would be:

```
def crc8_itu(msg):
    crc = 0
    for byte in msg:
        crc ^= byte
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ 7 if crc & 0x80 else crc << 1
        crc &= 0xff
    return crc ^ 0x55
```

Comment: The description of the 8-bit CRC on the chip: CRC-8-ATM (HEC): X8 + X2 + X0 + 1. The nine binary polynomial coefficients are: 100000111. The CRC calculation is preset with "1" data values. So as far as I understand the CRC poly would be 0x07 (discarding the MSB) I looked up the name of the CRC on this website https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.8 and found that the final XOR value is 0x55.

Comment: Then put that information in the question! We can't help you if you withhold information.

Comment: `0xe0` is the _same polynomial_ as `0x07`, just reflected for a reflected implementation. (Look at the bits.)

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I see how I left out useful information, turns out that after trying different combinations and after reading the C-code section on "https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa106a/sbaa106a.pdf?ts=1654773172842&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.bing.com%252F" that the CRC's init value is 0xFF and the final XOR value is 0x00.

Comment: I have validated this crc using "http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html?msclkid=391ec3dfcf8a11ecb97e68672e0a50b8", with the following values "custom crc" poly: 0x07,  initial value: 0xFF, Final XOR: 0x00. This setup gives me the result crc value "0xF4" when I give it "0x01" as input data. I have tested the chip in crc mode and it returns "0xF4" when it reads the value "0x01" from a register. So this CRC setup must be the one I'm looking for.

Comment: You were able to generate test data form your chip, and you left that out of the question as well?!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the CRC had other parameters than I expected.

Reading the C-code section in the [TI Application Report](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa106a/sbaa106a.pdf)
I see that the initial CRC-value is `0xFF` and the final XOR-value is `0x00`.

Using an [online calculator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) with [this setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lpmA.png),
I'm able to get the same CRC-result as the ADS1235.

Rewriting @Mark Adler's code:

```
def crc8_8_atm(msg):
    crc = 0xFF
    for byte in msg:
        crc ^= byte
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x07 if crc & 0x80 else crc << 1
        crc &= 0xff
    return crc ^ 0x00
```

Gives me the expected result.

Big thanks to @Mark Adler